# EF6 with SQLite one-to-many relationship failing on unique constraint without foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm running into an issue when inserting entities with one-to-many relationships with unique constraint into an SQLite database using Entity Framework 6 **without** using foreign keys and I **cannot** change this. Let's consider this example:

**Model**

```
public class Box {
    public int BoxId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}

public class Item {
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Box Box { get; set; }
}
```

**First Insertion of an Item with a new Box**

```
Box box = new Box(){BoxId = 1};
Item item = new Item(){ItemId = 1, Box = box};
using (var db = new MyDbContext()) {
    db.Items.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

This works and creates both the Item and the Box.

If I run again the same code as before I get a "unique contraint fail" error, because it cannot create another Box with Id = 1. So the solution would be:

**Validation of Box**

```
Box box = new Box(){BoxId = 1};
Item item = new Item(){ItemId = 1, Box = box};
using (var db = new MyDbContext()) {
    var box = db.Box.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == box.Id);
    item.Box = box ?? item.Box;
    db.Items.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Do I really always need to get the box from the DB? If yes, can I save the object in a cache and reuse it? How could I abstract getting the box? Could I create a BoxService and inside open a new scoped context to get the box?

I'm adding here the more or less the context and migration, since my real scenario involves more properties, but for sake of simplicity I only showed these models.

**Migration**

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Boxs",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
                   
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Boxs", x => x.Id);
                });
                
 migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Items",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    ItemId = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false)
                    BoxId = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: false),
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Items", x => x.ItemId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Items_Boxs_BoxId",
                        column: x => x.BoxId,
                        principalTable: "Boxs",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

**Context**

```
public class ItemsDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ItemsDbContext(DbContextOptions<ItemsDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Boxs> Boxs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Items> Items { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Boxs>().HasMany(s => s.Items).WithOne(s => s.Box);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can u share the DB context? and the migration scripts that has been generated by ef to create those models in DB

Comment: @odaiwa, I've updated the post with the context and migration, bare in mind this is hypotetical code since what I have is a bit more complex, but i think i manage to translate to this simplier code

Comment: What EF? EF6 or EF Core 6?

Comment: This is .net 6 application, so EF Core 6 using SQLite

Answer (score 0):

> Do I really always need to get the box from the DB? If yes, can I save the object in a cache and reuse it?

No, you don't, but you generally should. This is an association issue. You're wanting to create a new item but associate it with an existing Box. EF has no way of knowing if a Box reference it is handed represents an existing box or a new box unless you tell it. To do what you are looking for without fetching the box:

```
Box box = new Box(){BoxId = 1};
Item item = new Item(){ItemId = 1, Box = box};
using (var db = new MyDbContext()) {
    db.Attach(box); // <- Tells EF "treat this as an existing row"
    db.Items.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

That will work in this example because we scope a new DbContext which will be tracking nothing, and are only processing a single operation. If you have something like an injected DbContext instance that *might* be already tracking the desured box (loaded in another operation, or referenced by another item etc.) then you need a bit more work to ensure the operation is safe:

```
// where _db is a module level reference or otherwise reused DbContext instance...

Box box = _db.Boxes.Local.FirstOrDefault(x => x.BoxId == boxId); // <- Note .Local
bool boxExists = box != null;
if(!boxExists)
{
    box = new Box(){BoxId = boxId};
    _db.Attach(box);
}

Item item = new Item(){ItemId = 1, Box = box};
_db.Items.Add(item);
_db.SaveChanges();
if(!boxExists)
    _db.Entry(box).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

The first thing this does is check the local tracking cache for an existing Box. This doesn't go to the database, it just asks the DbContext to look for an existing tracked entity. If found, we use it, otherwise we create the box and attach it like the first example. Since this attached reference is now tracked, after we save the changes, it is a good idea to detach that "stubbed" box because typically this won't be a *complete* box, just a stub, and if we go to EF to fetch a box, we want a complete one, not a tracked stub that just has an ID set for instance.

The reason I say you should just EF to go to the database and fetch the box is that the above logic can be easy to screw up resulting in situational runtime bugs, and it also serves as a validation when you expect to reference an existing record, in a valid state to receive items, and a record that user has access to see. This gives you a meaningful validation point to assert rather than a FK exception on `SaveChanges` or worse, saving an item against the wrong/invalid box.

Comment: Thank you for the help, it works even tho I think I need to rework a bit. Just some follow up questions, on the first example, you "know" the box already exists, but for me to know I need to to at least a select on the context to know this right? 
On the second example the if is suppose to be if(boxExists) right? Because only if it exists we want to attach for EF to know it's not suppose to create. If this is true, the second if is also if(boxExists)?

Comment: The first example is an assumption that the box exists. If it doesn't exist you will get a FK exception on `SaveChanges`. The safest way is to query the entity, but say if the entity is pretty big and you just need to associate it you could do a less expensive query like `bool boxExists = db.Boxes.Any(x => x.BoxId == boxId);` This avoids loading the box and instead runs a very quick query. If True, create stub and attach. In the second example, it is correct. If the box exists in the cache we use that, if it does not exist we can attach (and detach) our stub.